# Let, $M \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. Determine all Jordan blocks of $M$ if $M^{2} = I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

We have that, $M^{2} = I$; hence, $M^{2} - I = 0$. Which means that the minimal polynomial of $M$ divides $x^2-1 = (x+1)(x-1)$. Which means the possible eigenvalues of $M$ are $\{-1,1\}$. We also have that the maximum size of the Jordan blocks corresponding to $-1$ and $1$ are at most $1$; hence, the possible Jordan blocks are the $1$ by $1$, $-1$ and $1$ Jordan block.

Does my solution look correct? Any errors? Thanks!

Comment: That looks fine.